# How to organize JavaScript assets in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to transform a static website to rails. At the moment I have following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#slider').s3Slider({  
     timeout: 3000
   });
});
```

in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` placed inside `head` tag. The   script is working fine(i.e. sliding few images).

I know this is not the right place to have javascript code.

**1. Could anyone help me to place this code in the right place in the assets?** and
**2. Will it work as it is or I will have to make changes?**

**Update**
In app/assets/javascripts/application.js I have the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require welcome
//= require_tree .
```

`aap/assets/javascripts/welcome.js` is the file that now contains the above mentioned javascript code

Comment: you can put it in `application.js` or create separate script file and put into there and add script file into application.js

Comment: @uzaif, placing it inside `application.js` works perfectly however placing it in a new file e.g. `welcome.js` and including it in `application.js` doesn't. Can you guess why?

Comment: If you're using Turbolinks (enabled by default), you might want to use `$(document).on('page:load', callback)` or `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', callback)` (depending on which version of Turbolinks you're using) instead of `$(document).ready(callback)`.

Comment: run `rake asset:precompile`

Comment: how are you requiring it in your application.js? Could you post the `application.js`

Comment: I believe `require_tree` already requires everything in the javascripts directory. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Finally got it working, I had two files by the name welcome, one with extension `.js` and another with the extension `.coffee`. After removing `welcome.coffee` the script has started working.